# How to combine slots of S4 class object in one vector

Tags: r

I created an S4 class with two slots for example

```
setClass("A", 
     slots = c(
         x = "numeric",
         y = "numeric"
     )
)
```

and created some objects

```
 l1<-new("A", x = 5, y = 8)
 l2<-new("A", x = 6, y = 7)
 l3<-new("A", x = 7, y = 6)
 l4<-new("A", x = 8, y = 5)
```

Now I want to combine slot x into one vector. I do it like

```
c<-c(l1@x,l2@x,l3@x,l4@x)
```

Is there any better way of doing this, preferably loop because no of objects is not fix.

Comment: How should R know which objects to extract the `x` slot for? Are you doing to type the list of objects? Are all these objects related somehow? It's easier to iterate a collection of objects if they are stored in a list but you do not seem to be doing that.

Comment: My objects are already in a list and I want to make barplot() for slot x and for slot y. For barplot it need to be in one object. Is there any way I could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes much easier to do if your 4 objects are contained in a list:

```
my.list <- list(l1, l2, l3, l4)

sapply(my.list, attr, 'x')

[1] 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks this seem to solve my problem. Can I construct barplot() for slot x directly or I would have to store it in an object like  c<- sapply(my.list, attr, 'x') and then barplot(c).

Comment: You'd have to store it in a vector first (which the code above will produce), then barplot that.